# Score tracking is not functioning in my "Rock Paper Scissors" game

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to Javascript and have decided on making a rock-paper-scissors game in an attempt to get comfortable with JS. Currently, I am noticing that when I click on a button (to choose rock, paper, or scissors), I notice that the score isn't keeping track of whether the player wins or the computer wins. This also leads me to wonder if the functions in the JS file are working or not, which I am also unsure of.

What I have in my files:

```js
const queryElement = (query) => document.querySelector(query);

const playerPoints = document.querySelector('#playerScore');
const computerPoints = document.querySelector('#computerScore');
const rockEl = queryElement("#rock");
const paperEl = queryElement("#paper");
const scissorsEl = queryElement("#scissors");

const choices = [rockEl, paperEl, scissorsEl];

function onSelection() {
  console.log(this.value);
}

let compScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;

function computerPlay() {
  let choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  return choices[Math.floor(choices.length * Math.random())];
}

function playRound(playerSelection) {
  let computerSelection = computerPlay()

  if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    playerPoints.textContent = ++playerScore
    return ("You Win!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    computerPoints.textContent = ++compScore
    return ("You Lose!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    return ("It's A Tie!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    playerPoints.textContent = ++playerScore
    return ("You Win!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    computerPoints.textContent = ++compScore
    return ("You Lose!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    return ("It's A Tie!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "Scissors" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    playerPoints.textContent = ++playerScore
    return ("You Win!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "Scissors" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    computerPoints.textContent = ++compScore
    return ("You Lose!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "Scissors" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    return ("It's A Tie!");
  } else
    return ("Uh oh, something went wrong");
}

document.getElementById('rock').onclick;
document.getElementById('paper').onclick;
document.getElementById('scissors').onclick;

function gameEnd() {
  if (playerScore > computerScore) {
    console.log("Game Over! You Win!");
  } else if (computerScore > userScore) {
    console.log("Game Over! You Lose!")
  }
}

function game() {
  console.log(playRound(playerSelection));
  if (playerScore < 5 && computerScore < 5) {
    game()
  } else {
    gameEnd();
  }
}

choices.forEach((choice) => {
  choice.addEventListener("click", onSelection);
});
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="rules">
    <p>Which do you choose?</p>
    <p>First to score 5 wins</p>
  </div>

  <div class="scores">
    <div id="playerScore">
      <p>Player: 0</p>
    </div>

    <div id="computerScore">
      <p>Computer: 0</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="rock" type="submit" value="rock"><img src="./images/rock.svg" alt="rock"></button>
    <button id="paper" type="submit" value="paper"><img src="./images/paper.svg" alt="paper"></button>
    <button id="scissors" type="submit" value="scissors"><img src="./images/scissors.svg" alt="scissors"></button>
  </div>
  <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
</main>
```

Comment: I've made your question into a runnable snippet but I had to correct two things in the HTML... 1) You had `</P>` instead of `</p>`, and 2) Missing `</main>`

Comment: What is `document.getElementById('rock').onclick;` (and the other two similar lines) supposed to do? Your main issue appears to be that nothing calls `playRound()`

Comment: Ah good catch. Didn't realize I capitalized the P and left out `</main>`
I was looking to connect the three buttons that you see at the bottom of the HTML file with my JS file and came upon `document.getElementByID('rock').onclick;`